# Loss of precision?

Tags: c++, g++, precision

I have a function like:

```
double calc( double x );
```

Do I lose precision with any of these expressions:

```
double y1 = calc( 1.0 / 3 );
double y2 = calc( 1.0 / 3.0 );
```

Are these more accurate:

```
double y3 = calc( static_cast<double>(1) / 3 )
double y4 = calc( static_cast<double>(1) / static_cast<double>(3) )
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I had the wrong numbers here.

But, what I meant was that is `1.0` interpreted as `float` or `double` and is that always the case or does it depend on some compiler flags? If it is a `float`, then `1.0/3` would also be a `float` and only afterwards be converted into a `double`. If this is the case, it would cause loss of precision, wouldn't it?

**EDIT 2**

I have tested this with `g++` and as it turns out, if the program is compiled with `-fsingle-precision-constant` flag, you **do** lose precision.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <typeinfo>

long double calc( long double val)
{
  return val;
}
int main() {
  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits< long double >::max_digits10);

  std::cout << calc(1.0/3.0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << calc(static_cast<float>(1)/3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << calc(static_cast<double>(1)/3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << calc(static_cast<long double>(1)/3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(1.0).name() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The results are,

```
0.333333343267440795898
0.333333343267440795898
0.33333333333333331483
0.333333333333333333342
f
```

So, I decided to use `static_cast< long double >(1) / 3` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Dunno.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: All of these expressions will lead to the same result, No loss of precision at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the alternatives you show gives any loss of precision [at least not if the compiler does what the standard says it should do]. Which is that all binary operators where one operand is a `double`, the other side automatically gets promoted to `double` [and in general, when two operands are different size, they are promoted to the larger one].

In particular, integer values [below the mantissa's number of bits] are always represented precisely.

[Obviously, we have no idea what `calc` does with your input - that may be the source of any and all kinds of errors, but I'm presuming you are actually asking if `3.0/8.0` will always be `0.375` in the cases you have suggested - of course `3/8` will result in zero, since that is integer on both sides]

edit in response to the original question being edited:

If the code says `1.` or `1.0` or `0.3` or `.3`, it is a `double`. If you write `0.5f`, it is a `float`. As per the rules above `1.0/3` will be the result of `double(1.0)/double(3.0)`.

It is technically possible for a compiler to support only one floating point type, with 3 different ways of writing that - the C and C++ standards has no requirement for `double` to have more bits than `float`.

Comment: I have edited the question. Would you mind taking another look and revising your answer?

Comment: Still applies. I added a bit of clarification as to why.

Answer (score 0):

No. The constant expression for `y1` is **implicitly** converted into a `double`. The constant expression for `y2` is already a `double`.

What you are doing in `y3` and `y4` is defining a constant integer value and casting it to a `double`, when you can simply defining a double-precision floating-point constant as you have already done.

Comment: A bit more accurately, for `y1` the `8` is (implicitly) converted to `double` to match the `3.0`. The result of dividing those two doubles has type double; no conversion needed there.